# markdown table not rendering properly with lines

Tags: markdown, apache-superset

I put markdown layout in my superset dashboard. I have to create a table but it doesn't work properly.

The markdown I used is

```
| type|name |description |
|----|---|---|
| blahg | dbah | agsr |
| 12 | 1ga | afbv |
```

and how superset shows it is like this below. How can I fix this and create a table with lines?

[image]